# tuples (arrays) as attributes in mongoose.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB, and mongoose.js specifically, allows tuples as attributes.  For instance, the [MongoDB documentation has this example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) where the attribute `comments` is itself an array of objects with the attributes `[{body: String, date: Date}]`. Yay!

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
})
```

Now when i persist that to MongoDB, not only does each instance of `blogSchema` get its own value for _id (e.g. `502efea0db22660000000002`) but each individual value of `comment` gets its own `_id` field.

For the most part I don't care, but in my app the analog to `comments` may have thousands of values.  Each of which gets its own huge value of `_id`.

Can I prevent that?  I'll never need to refer to them individually. Or should I learn to stop worrying and love the unique identifier?  I grew up programming the Vic20 and TRS80 as a kid, so may be overly paranoid about wasting memory/storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_id` can be disabled by setting the `noId` schema option to `true`. To pass the option you need to pass an instance of schema instead of using the object literal:

```
// instead of this...
comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }]

// do this...
var commentSchema = new Schema({ body: String, date: Date }, { noId: true });
var blogSchema = new Schema({
  ..
  comments: [commentSchema]
})
```